# How to forward from example.com/en to example.com/en/ with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am stuck trying to write a rewrite rule for my htaccess file which should forward from for example www.example.com/en to www.example.com/en/

I tried: `RewriteRule ^en/?$ en [L]`
but nothing happens. Does someone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is `/en/` a physical directory under DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: No its also a rewrite rule which will rewrite /en/ to index.php?lang=en

Comment: OK 2 questions then: `1. `Did the answer provided by toscho work for you? `2. ` What is the reason of this `/en` to `/en/` forward since you're already forwarding `/en/` to `index.php?lang=en`?

Comment: Maybe its not the right way, but I want that /en/ should be the standard forwarding to index.php?lang=en and if a user types in /en this should forward him to /en/ (which will then of course forward to index.php?lang=en). The answer doesnt change anything, it doesnt work.

Comment: Alright I think now I understand what you're trying to do. Please see my answer below and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ok, now whatever I type in it will put a / behind it, wont it?
Now what also has to work is that if there is something behind the /en/, for example /en/login this should forward me to index.php?lang=en&action=login
Before I did it like this:
`RewriteRule ^en/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&lang=en [L]`
Now how would I do it in your example?

Comment: You should flip the parameters around. So it will become `RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [L]`. Optionally change `[L]` to `[L,R]` the also change the url in the browsers address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?![^/]*/).*$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?action=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will:

- **externally redirect**: `/en` to `/en/` and **internally redirect** this to `/index.php?lang=en`
- **internall redirect**: `/fr/login` to `/index.php?action=login&lang=fr`

**Additionally:** As per your comment you will need this rule to add www in domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer for your requirement. Also keep in mind that it will **not** add trailing slash `/` to everything. It will only do so for a URI that is not a file or directory.

Comment: very nice, just one thing, there shouldnt be a / after the login, so it should be /fr/login

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have tested them and it is working fine. Pls do full copy/paste this code into your file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the forwarding from /en to /en/ doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Are you sure? because it is still adding trailing slash for me after `/en`. Suggest you to restart your browser or clear your cache.

Comment: Nope, it tells me 404 Not Found. Works not in any browser.

Comment: Works for me in all the browsers. You can try swapping this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/[^/]*/` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$`

Comment: That will change /en to /en/ but unfortunately also /en/login to /en/login/

Comment: That's correct but since the other rule is not working for you. And in any case it should not matter since eventually it will be forwarded to `/index.php?action=login&lang=en`

Comment: Yeah in fact it doesnt matter, its just maybe prettier if you see /en/login cos you know that login is not a directory. And its also better for SEO.

Comment: For SEO purpose I 'm sure `/en/login` will have same effect as `/en/login/`. In any case I have just updated the code to have the same effect with negative lookahead. Pls try and let me know. It again works fine in my testing.

Comment: Do you know how to add a rewrite engine into the above code which should always forward from `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`? Because using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]` will give me an infinite loop.

Comment: Wow thanks! One last general question, is there a way to do something like different cases? For example `www.example.com/en/` should have a backslash at the end, but `www.example.com/register` should not have one. So is there something like `if(something == "en") { add_backslash }...`

Answer (score 0):

Use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent):

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/en$ /en/
```